# Percentage chance for successful techcopy?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

In Blitzball, if you have a skill you can learn, and try to techcopy... why does it keep failing? I am trying to learn Anti-venom 2. My player is double the level of the opponent, but keeps failing on the tech-copy.  Any specifics into the percentage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are hitting the "x" button at the right time? If you get the timing wrong, you won't be able to get the tech, regardless of levels.